# VBS script to rename files using the pathname

Tags: vbscript, rename

i am new to VBS scripting and I have done few stuff with Excel VBA before. Now I have a script which renames single files with the pathname of the files (truncated to 4 letter each))see below. It is some script which I modified a bit to fit my purpose. However, I would like to automatize the file rename process and rename all files in a folder and its subfolders in the same way the scipt works for single files. Can anybody help me with this question?

```
Set Shell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set Parameter = WScript.Arguments
For i = 0 To Parameter.Count - 1
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    findFolder = fso.GetParentFolderName(Parameter(i))
    PathName = fso.GetAbsolutePathName(Parameter(i))
    FileExt = fso.GetExtensionName(Parameter(i))
    Search = ":"
    findFolder2= Right(PathName, Len(PathName) - InStrRev(PathName, Search))
    arr = Split(findFolder2, "\")
    For j=0 To UBound(arr)-1
    arr(j) = ucase(Left(arr(j), 4))
    Next
    joined = Join(arr, "%")   
    prefix = right(joined, len(joined)-1)    
    fso.MoveFile Parameter(i), findFolder + "\" + prefix 
next
```

Hoping that I can get some useful ideas.

Herbie

Answer (score 1):

Walking a tree requires recursion, a function calling itself for each level.

```
On Error Resume Next
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dirname = InputBox("Enter Dir name")
ProcessFolder DirName

Sub ProcessFolder(FolderPath)
    On Error Resume Next
    Set fldr = fso.GetFolder(FolderPath)

    Set Fls = fldr.files
    For Each thing in Fls
         msgbox Thing.Name & " " & Thing.DateLastModified 
    Next

    Set fldrs = fldr.subfolders
    For Each thing in fldrs
        ProcessFolder thing.path
    Next

End Sub
```

From Help on how to run another file.

```
Set Shell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
shell.Run(strCommand, [intWindowStyle], [bWaitOnReturn])
```

So outside the loop,

```
Set Shell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
```

And in the loop

```
shell.Run("wscript Yourscript.vbs thing.name, 1, True)
```

Also the VBS help file has recently been taken down at MS web site. It is available on my skydrive at https://1drv.ms/f/s!AvqkaKIXzvDieQFjUcKneSZhDjw It's called script56.chm.

Comment: Hi,Thanks alot for the help. I tried to substitute the line with the msgbox with my current script hoping that if it calls the script for each file this would work but it failed. If I insert only thing.name = "hello.txt", it just renames one file...do I need to write a separate sub for my renaming script and then call it from the thing. object?

Comment: ah...ok this is because it cannot rename more than one file with the same name...using

Comment: HI...thanks a lot. This helps already a lot. I managed to rename all files using a very simple argument like thing.name = i & ".txt" whereby i is a iterator. However, my procedure to rename files is quite complex. So once I would like to incorporate the script it does not work. Is there a possibility to use my script as it is and then to call it from the recursion?? Thanks a lot-

Comment: Made an edit. Also the VBS help file has recently been taken down at MS web site. It is available on my skydrive at https://1drv.ms/f/s!AvqkaKIXzvDieQFjUcKneSZhDjw It's called script56.chm.

Comment: Shell.Run("WScript rename.vbs thing.name, 1, True")

Comment: If in doubt use full paths. Wscript will always be found. `Shell.Run("WScript c:\somefolder\rename.vbs " & thing.path, 1, True)`. It matters if the paths have spaces.

Comment: I worked further on my renaming script and managed with the help of the above sample for recursion to rename all files in a folder and the respective subfolders. However, in some cases, depending on the depth of the subfolder level the script redundantly adds the path in to the filename. Does anyone know what could be the problem. Apart from that it does what it should and works well. Thanks a lot. I will post the code.