# Renaming multiple files recursively and copying them in a specific folder

Tags: vbscript, batch-rename

My image file name format is as below:

```
kris_1_verify_2016-01-01_12-05-20_00_000034.bmp
```

My main condition to rename -> if string 'verify' exist. 

Other conditions to rename complete file format are as below

1. Replace name string with a user id (for ex: 'kris' with 6010011).
2. Prefix to the name string should be fp_
3. After userid there should be another id which exist in original format
   for name string (for ex: digit 1 in 'kris_1')
4. After id number of image count should start with 00.
5. Finally format should end with _V.bmp.
6. After renaming file should created a folder with user id(ex: 6010011) and
   need to copy all files in that folder.

Final output format should be as below:

```
fp_6010011_5_00_V.bmp
fp_6010011_5_01_V.bmp
fp_6010011_5_02_V.bmp
fp_6010011_5_03_V.bmp
fp_6010011_5_05_V.bmp
```

Can anyone please help on renaming multiple files recursively and copying them in a specific folder

Comment: Welcome to [so].  You are more likely to get some help here if you can demonstrate that you have made an effort to resolve the question yourself rather than posting requirements for someone to code for you.  We are here to help you fix your coding problems, not to do your work for you.  Please take the time to read [ask] and demonstrate what you have already attempted yourself, and explain where you need help

Comment: See my answer here on how to walk a tree. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40053070/vbs-script-to-rename-files-using-the-pathname/40053202#40053202